# R.java problems with generating

Tags: android, r.java-file

I tryed to create new project and in my R.java there was next code, for example:

```
public static final class layout {
public static int activity_main=0x7f030000;
```

instead of

```
public static final class layout {
public static final int activity_main=0x7f030000;
```

So I can't build project normally, because it generates **public static int** without **final**.

What should I do?

Comment: R.java is generated by your compiler. If your src files are correct & your res/*.xml files are correct, then R.java will also be correct

Comment: but it isn't corrent ( I have clear windows, where I installed need programms only (Eclipse, Android ADT, etc.)

Comment: I dont understand. Make sure you have no errors in your res/*.xml. Make sure that all the elements in your xml files that have a "@" are resolved. Also check your xml files for lines like : android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize". Make sure its resolved.

Comment: Then you need to follow instructions in the given answer

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on project --> Android Tools -->fix project properties

before doing this remove import statement like

```
import android.R.*..
```

or try clean project from

project --> clean

Comment: right click on porject 
Buildpath --> configure buildpath --> remove all android library

then try
Right Click on project --> Android Tools -->fix project properties

it will work

Comment: Error: case expressions must be constant expressions ActivityMain.java

Comment: No, becase it has commentary :/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

Comment: It seems that your error has nothing to do with your original question

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of many things.
1. Check your xml files have no errors in them as this can stop R.Java from being automatically generated.
2. Clean your project. This will rebuild your project.
3. Delete any android.R import statements.
4. Close and re-open eclipse.

I also wouldn't recommended fiddling with the R.Java file dirctley.